# Rotate label text in seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, x-axis

I have a simple factorplot

```
import seaborn as sns
g = sns.factorplot("name", "miss_ratio", "policy", dodge=.2, 
    linestyles=["none", "none", "none", "none"], data=df[df["level"] == 2])
```

[image]

The problem is that the x labels all run together, making them unreadable. How do you rotate the text so that the labels are readable?

Comment: This helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74715767/how-to-rotate-the-xticks-in-a-seaborn-objects-v0-12x-plot

Comment: For `seaborn.objects` with **v0.12**, see [How to rotate the xticks with seaborn.objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74715767/7758804)

Answer (score 276, accepted):

You can rotate tick labels with the `tick_params` method on matplotlib `Axes` objects. To provide a specific example:

```
ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=90)
```

Comment: This works but ax should be g for this example: g.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=90)

Answer (score 435):

I had a problem with the answer by @mwaskorn, namely that

```
g.set_xticklabels(rotation=30)
```

fails, because this also requires the labels. A bit easier than the answer by @Aman is to just add

```
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
```

Comment: You can also get the labels like so `g.set_xticklabels(g.get_xticklabels(), rotation=30)`. Assign it to a variable if you want to suppress the output.

Comment: I think this is correct, when setting `plt.xtics` worked for me.

Comment: tried all the options above for a violin plot and plt.xticks(rotation=n) is only one I could get to work

Comment: When I try this, my xticklabels are no longer aligned with the x ticks. Does anyone know why?

Comment: I recommend to also add `plt.tight_layout()`, so that the margins are adjusted to fit the text

Comment: `g.set_xticklabels(rotation=30)` works on `FacetGrid` now

Comment: `g.tick_params('x', rotation=90)` seems to work as of September 2022.

Answer (score 37):

This is still a matplotlib object. Try this:

```
# <your code here>
locs, labels = plt.xticks()
plt.setp(labels, rotation=45)
```

Answer (score 22):

Any seaborn plots suported by facetgrid won't work with (e.g. catplot)

```
g.set_xticklabels(rotation=30)
```

however barplot, countplot, etc. will work as they are not supported by facetgrid. Below will work for them.

```
g.set_xticklabels(g.get_xticklabels(), rotation=30)
```

Also, in case you have 2 graphs overlayed on top of each other, try set_xticklabels on graph which supports it.

Answer (score 13):

If anyone wonders how to this for clustermap CorrGrids (part of a given seaborn example):

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(context="paper", font="monospace")

# Load the datset of correlations between cortical brain networks
df = sns.load_dataset("brain_networks", header=[0, 1, 2], index_col=0)
corrmat = df.corr()

# Set up the matplotlib figure
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 9))

# Draw the heatmap using seaborn
g=sns.clustermap(corrmat, vmax=.8, square=True)
rotation = 90 
for i, ax in enumerate(g.fig.axes):   ## getting all axes of the fig object
     ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation = rotation)


g.fig.show()
```

Answer (score 13):

You can also use `plt.setp` as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

plot=sns.barplot(data=df,  x=" ", y=" ")
plt.setp(plot.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)
```

to rotate the labels 90 degrees.

Answer (score 8):

For a [`seaborn.heatmap`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html), you can rotate these using (based on [@Aman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26540254/1587329))

```
pandas_frame = pd.DataFrame(data, index=names, columns=names)
heatmap = seaborn.heatmap(pandas_frame)
loc, labels = plt.xticks()
heatmap.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=45)
heatmap.set_yticklabels(labels[::-1], rotation=45) # reversed order for y
```

Answer (score 2):

If the labels have long names it may be hard to get it right. A solution that worked well for me using `catplot` was:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ax.tick_params(labelrotation=45)`. You can apply this to the axes figure from the plot without having to provide labels. This is an alternative to using the FacetGrid if that's not the path you want to take.