# how to display the x axis labels in seaborn data visualisation library on a vertical plane rather than horizontal

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I would like X axis labels on factorplots (which are dates) to be vertical up the screen rather than horizonal (as horizontal takes up too much space).

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rotate label text in seaborn factorplot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540035/rotate-label-text-in-seaborn-factorplot)

Answer (score 0):

This is, IMO, the stickiest point with matplotlib. You have to rotate each label individually.

I always keep this function handy:

```
def rotateTickLabels(ax, rotation, which, rotation_mode='anchor', ha='right'):
    axes = []
    if which in ['x', 'both']:
        axes.append(ax.xaxis)

    elif which in ['y', 'both']:
        axes.append(ax.yaxis)

    for axis in axes:
        for t in axis.get_ticklabels():
            t.set_horizontalalignment(ha)
            t.set_rotation(rotation)
            t.set_rotation_mode(rotation_mode)
```

So then you use it like this:

```
import matploltib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# ... plot stuff
rotateTickLabels(ax, 30, 'x')
```