# Rotate tick labels for seaborn barplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to display a chart with rotated x-axis labels, but the chart is not displaying.

```
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

yellow='#FFB11E'
by_school=sns.barplot(x ='Organization Name',y ='Score',data = combined.sort('Organization Name'),color=yellow,ci=None)
```

At this point I can see the image, but after I set the xticklabel, I don't see the image anymore only an object reference. (I would post the image, but I don't enough reputation :()

```
by_school.set_xticklabels('Organization Name',rotation=45)

<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x3971a6a0>
```

A similar question is posted here: [Rotate label text in seaborn factorplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540035/rotate-label-text-in-seaborn-factorplot)  but the solution is not working.

Comment: Are you rotating the label in the same notebook cell it was created? You need to be

Comment: No I wasn't, but now that I am getting this error: set_xticklabels() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You need a different method call, namely `.set_rotation` for each `ticklable`s.
Since you already have the ticklabels, just change their rotations:

```
for item in by_school.get_xticklabels():
    item.set_rotation(45)
```

`barplot` returns a `matplotlib.axes` object (as of `seaborn` 0.6.0), therefore you have to rotate the labels this way. In other cases, when the method returns a `FacetGrid` object, refer to [Rotate label text in seaborn factorplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540035/rotate-label-text-in-seaborn-factorplot?lq=1)

Comment: Could also do `plt.setp(by_school.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45)` to save yourself a line of code :)

Comment: Also `set_xticklabels` doesn't take positions (unlike `plt.xticks`, an example of an annoying inconsistency in the state machine/object oriented APIs) but the original code didn't work because OP was just passing a single string not a list of labels.

Comment: You could also use `plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')` if you imported matplotlib.pyplot as plt.

Comment: To make the answer a one-liner (if it's important to save one line): `[item.set_rotation(45) for item in by_school.get_xticklabels()]`

Comment: This works for me although if I include a title in the seaborn plot, i.e. `sns.barplot(...).set_title('My title')` , I get AttributeError: 'Text' object has no attribute 'get_xticklabels'. Is there a way around it?

Comment: @MagnusPersson please do not use list comprehensions when you do not require the output. They should be reserved for list generation, and not for set methods.

Answer (score 64):

You can rotate seaborn xticks like so:

```
sns.barplot(x='Organization Name', y='Score', data=df)

plt.xticks(rotation=70)
plt.tight_layout()
```

Comment: This does not work for me - specifically the plt.xticks overwrites the barplot with an empty one (with rotated ticks). Should I do something differently? I use Python 3.7 and Spyder.

Comment: @Dudelstein maybe try upgrading your packages to make sure you're on the latest versions. I suspect some older packages or package version mismatches. Also check that you're using the proper installed package you think you are with `import seaborn as sns`; `sns.__file__` and `sns.__version__` for example. If you have multiple Python installations you can sometimes use different packages. from different installations accidentally

Answer (score 49):

Use the following code statement:

```
by_school.set_xticklabels(by_school.get_xticklabels(), 
                          rotation=90, 
                          horizontalalignment='right')
```

Comment: Also add `horizontalalignment='right'` so that the labels match the ticks.

Answer (score 4):

If you come here to rotate the labels for a [`seaborn.heatmap`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html), the following should work (based on [@Aman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26540254/1587329) at [Rotate label text in seaborn factorplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540035/rotate-label-text-in-seaborn-factorplot))

```
pandas_frame = pd.DataFrame(data, index=names, columns=names)
heatmap = seaborn.heatmap(pandas_frame)
loc, labels = plt.xticks()
heatmap.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=45)
heatmap.set_yticklabels(labels[::-1], rotation=45) # reversed order for y
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'xticks'` When this was tried to be reproduced. Any thoughts?

Comment: @bmc: Which `matplotlib.__version__` were you using? For version `2.0.0`, `plt.xticks()` worked: ``import seaborn as sns;
import pandas as pd;
import numpy as np;
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;
df = pd.DataFrame(np.eye(3), range(3), range(3));
hm = sns.heatmap(df);
plt.xticks();
``

Answer (score -5):

This worked for me:

```
g.fig.autofmt_xdate()
```