# Rotate xtick labels in seaborn boxplot?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a question that is basically the same as a question back from 2014 (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540035/rotate-label-text-in-seaborn-factorplot)). However, my script still throws an error.

Here is what I do: I have a pandas dataframe with a few columns. I plot a simple boxplot comparison.

```
g = sns.boxplot(x='categories', y='oxygen', hue='target', data=df)
g.set_xticklabels(rotation=30)
```

The graph looks like this:

[image]

I'd like to rotate the x-labels by 30 degrees. Hence I use `g.set_xticklabels(rotation=30)`. However, I get the following error:

`set_xticklabels() missing 1 required positional argument: 'labels'`

I don't know how to pass the `matplotlib` `labels` argument to seaborns `sns.boxplot`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

The question you link to uses a `factorplot`. A factorplot returns its own class which has a method called `set_xticklabels(rotation)`. This is different from the `set_xticklabels` method of the matplotlib `Axes`.

In the linked question's answers there are also other options which you may use

```
ax = sns.boxplot(x='categories', y='oxygen', hue='target', data=df)
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(),rotation=30)
```

or

```
ax = sns.boxplot(x='categories', y='oxygen', hue='target', data=df)
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45)
```

Comment: Thanks, Do you have any idea why `myplot.set_xticklabels(myplot.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45)` not working but `plt.setp(myplot.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45)` works?

Comment: Maybe I was not clear. The second answer works when I use it, the first makes the labels disappear.

Comment: Both solutions work when I use them. I suppose the problem you're having is outside of the two lines shown here.

Comment: Hi, great tip @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, many thanks! Do you know why I keep getting a big text below the graph? My boxplot is ok, the output has no problem at all, however, I got several lines why the labels, for example 
[Text(0, 0, '1984'),
 Text(0, 0, '1985'),

Comment: @dekio put ; at the end of the line

Answer (score 5):

If you do not need to reset labels: `ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=90)`