# boxplot - python - label's text - how to change the font size

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

i have a problem with font size for y label.

[this is boxplot and the text is unreadable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXvAf.png)

Can you help me with that?
code:

```
sns.boxplot(x='purpose',y='fico',data=loans,linewidth=2.5,width=0.5)
plt.xlabel('purpose',fontsize=12)
plt.yscale('linear')
```

Comment: This question had an answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44954123/rotate-xtick-labels-in-seaborn-boxplot