# Rotate xtick labels (not ticks) in seaborn plot after adding lowess line

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn, statsmodels

this is a bit detailed, but help appreciated. It's a slightly annoying feature of seaborn that regplot can't handle datetime axes. This is especially so when you want to use the lowess parameter, which estimates local means to give a curve (as opposed to line) that tracks changes in a plot. (This functionality is available in R, for instance.)

This is a problem for me because I have a linear plot that I'd like to smooth out but without using a rolling mean. This is my plot:

[image: No Lowess line]

To solve this problem, I took the index of my dataframe as the x-axis, and used statsmodels to calculate the lowess line as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import statsmodels.api as sm

rated = pd.read_csv('filepath.csv')

rated['linear'] = rated.index

x = rated['linear']
y = rated['trust_num']

lowess = sm.nonparametric.lowess(y, x, frac=.2)


low_y = [i[1] for i in lowess]
low_x = [i[0] for i in lowess]

rated['low_y'] = low_y
rated['low_x'] = low_x

rated['low_y'] = low_y
rated['low_x'] = low_x

h = sns.lineplot(x = 'linear', y = 'trust_num', data = rated)
h = sns.lineplot(x = 'linear', y = 'low_y', data = rated, color = 'r')
```

This produces exactly what I'd like:
[image: Lowess line]

The final step comes with assigning dates to the x-axis, which I do as follows:

```
labels = [i for i in rated['date']]
h.set_xticklabels(labels)
```

The result is a clustered x-axis, as below:
[image: bad dates]

Fair enough, this is a common plotting problem. So I try to rotate my xtick labels:

```
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
```

But it makes no difference. Can anyone advise how I might declutter the axis? Seems a pain to nearly get there and fall at a seemingly simple problem!

Comment: Try rotating in the call to `set_xticklabels()`?

Comment: Independent of the rotation problem I think this approach will show you the wrong dates.

Comment: @DavidG: This solved the rotation problem––thanks!

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: You're exactly right: it's the same date over and over again. I'll need to think about this ...

Comment: This is because you have dates in `rated` but only 9 labels. The main point is: Never set the labels without setting their position as well. Here, the use of a `FuncFormatter` might make more sense.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Duly noted, thanks. That should save me no end of trouble. Much obliged!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rotate label text in seaborn factorplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540035/rotate-label-text-in-seaborn-factorplot)