# How can I rotate axis labels in a faceted seaborn.objects plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, seaborn-0.12.x

I am working with the excellent `seaborn.objects` module in the most recent version of **seaborn**.

I would like to produce a plot:

- With rotated x-axis labels
- With facets

Rotating x-axis labels is not directly supported within `seaborn.objects` (and standard stuff like `plt.xticks()` after making the graph doesn't work), but the documentation suggests doing it using the `.on()` method. `.on()` takes a **matplotlib** figure/subfigure or axis object and builds on top of it. As I pointed out in my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74715767/how-to-rotate-the-xticks-in-a-seaborn-objects-v0-12x-plot/75039104#75039104), the following code works to rotate axis labels:

```py
import seaborn.objects as so
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4],
                   'b':[5,6,7,8],
                   'c':['a','a','b','b']})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(rotation=90)

(so.Plot(df, x = 'a', y = 'b')
 .add(so.Line())
 .on(ax))
```

However, if I add facets by changing the graph code to

```py
(so.Plot(df, x = 'a', y = 'b')
 .add(so.Line())
 .on(ax)
 .facet('c'))
```

I get the error `Cannot create multiple subplots after calling Plot.on with a <class 'matplotlib.axes._axes.Axes'> object. You may want to use a <class 'matplotlib.figure.SubFigure'> instead.`

However, if I follow the instruction, and instead use the `fig` object, rotating the axes in that, I get a strange dual x-axis, one with rotated labels unrelated to the data, and the actual graph's labels, unrotated:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.xticks(rotation = 90)

(so.Plot(df, x = 'a', y = 'b')
 .add(so.Line())
 .on(fig)
 .facet('c'))
```

[image: Faceted graph with strange dual labeling]

How can I incorporate rotated axis labels with facets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're ending up with multiple axes plotted on top of each other. Note the parameter description for [`Plot.on`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.objects.Plot.on.html):

> Passing `matplotlib.axes.Axes` will add artists without otherwise modifying the figure. Otherwise, subplots will be created within the space of the given `matplotlib.figure.Figure` or `matplotlib.figure.SubFigure`.

Additionally, the `pyplot` functions (i.e. `plt.xticks`) only operate on the "current" axes, not all axes in the current figure.

So, two step solution:

- Only initialize the figure externally, and delegate subplot creation to `Plot`
- Use matplotlib's object-oriented interface to modify the tick label parameters

Example:

```
fig = plt.figure()

(so.Plot(df, x = 'a', y = 'b')
 .add(so.Line())
 .on(fig)
 .facet('c')
 .plot()
)

for ax in fig.axes:
    ax.tick_params("x", rotation=90)
```

[image]

Note that it will likely become possible to control tick label rotation directly through the `Plot` API, although rotating tick labels (especially to 90 degrees) is often not the best way to make overlapping labels readable.