# How can I use .on(fig) without distorting the legend position in seaborn.objects?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, seaborn-0.12.x

I am creating a plot in **seaborn.objects**. This plot has a legend, and I would also like to change its size.

This can be done using the `.theme()` method, which affects the **matplotlib** `rcParams`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn.objects as so
import pandas as pd

dat = pd.DataFrame({'group':['a','a','b','b'],
                    'x': [1, 2, 1, 2],
                    'y': [4, 3, 2, 1]})

# Choosing a very distorted figure size here so you can see when it works
(so.Plot(dat, x = 'x', y = 'y', color = 'group')
 .add(so.Line())
 .theme({'figure.figsize': (8,2)}))
```

[image: Line graph with legend and (8,2) figure size]

However, in order to solve the problem outlined in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75039156/how-can-i-rotate-axis-labels-in-a-faceted-seaborn-objects-plot/75041356#75041356), I need to create a **matplotlib** figure object and then graph `.on()` that. When I do this, the `'figure.figsize'` setting in `.theme()` is ignored (some other `.theme()` settings do still work, but not this one or a couple others I've tried). Also if you look closely you can see the right edge of the legend being pushed off the edge of the image.

(Note also that the `'legend.loc'` `rcParam` is ignored with or without `.on(fig)`: **seaborn.objects** has its own legend placement system I think.)

```py
fig = plt.figure()

# Choosing a very distorted figure size here so you can see when it works
(so.Plot(dat, x = 'x', y = 'y', color = 'group')
 .on(fig)
 .add(so.Line())
 .theme({'figure.figsize': (8,2)}))
```

[image: Line graph with legend and a figure size that is not (8,2)]

I can, however, now set `figsize` in the `plt.figure()` function. But when I do this, the legend positioning is thrown much further out of whack and is largely cut off.

```py
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8,2))

# Choosing a very distorted figure size here so you can see when it works
(so.Plot(dat, x = 'x', y = 'y', color = 'group')
 .on(fig)
 .add(so.Line()))
```

[image: Line graph with misplaced legend and (8,2) figure size]

How can I include both `.on(fig)` with a legend without pushing the legend away? As pointed out in this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73747899/how-to-move-the-legend-position-in-the-seaborn-objects-api) standard tools designed for legend movement in regular **matplotlib**/**seaborn** don't work in the same way for **seaborn.objects**. Although to be clear, my question isn't really about how to move the legend (while that would be one way to fix this problem) - **seaborn.objects** already knows how to properly place the legend for a resized figure if it's through `.theme()`, I ideally just want that to work through `plt.figure()` too.

(Edit: immediately after posting it occurred to me to try changing the `figsize` using the `rcParams` but from within **matplotlib** but this doesn't matter: `import matplotlib as mpl; mpl.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (8,2)` produces the same result as the `fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8,2))` attempt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what's happening here but it looks like it can be fixed by using `layout="tight"` when you create the figure:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 2), layout="tight")

(so.Plot(dat, x = 'x', y = 'y', color = 'group')
 .on(fig)
 .add(so.Line())
)
```

[image]